# I want to write a program that allows the user to guess a number between 0 and 100 in 7 attempts. I don't know why is this not working

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rnd = (int)(Math.random() * 101);

        System.out.println("The program is going to give a number that is between 0 and 100 (including them). You can guess it by pressing Run.");
        System.out.println("Enter your number:");
        int num = scan.nextInt();

        for (int count = 1; count <= 7; count++) {
            while (num != rnd) {
                if (num < rnd) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too low.");
                }
                if (num > rnd) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too high.");
                }
                if ((Math.abs(rnd - num) == 1) || (Math.abs(rnd - num) == 2)) {
                    System.out.println("But your guess is VERY close.");
                }
                num = scan.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println("You got it right!");
        }
        System.out.println("You should guess it in 7 tries.");
    }
}
```

So I used two loops and just nested them. Is that how it works for this? Right now the code is like starting with for loop and if that is true it goes to the while loop part where the guessing number takes place. Can this be fixed with just moving some codes and fixing minor areas around?

Comment: Remember to pick a good answer when you get one you like.

Answer (score 3):

What you should do in a situation like this is do the code manually. Literally. Grab a piece of paper and pretend you're a computer. It's a good exercise, and it will help you figure out your problem.

The problem is your inner loop. It loops until they guess correctly regardless of the number of attempts. Then you force them to do it 6 more times with the outer loop.

You really only need 1 loop. I would have a single loop like this:

```
int attempts = 0;
int num = 0;
do {
    num = scan.nextInt();
    ... most of the if code from your inner loop but not another scan.nextInt
} while (++attempts < 7 && num != rnd);
// and here you look at num == rnd to see if success or failures
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int rnd = (int) (Math.random() * 101);

    System.out.println("The program is going to give a number that is between 0 and 100 (including them). You can guess it by pressing Run.");
    System.out.println("Enter your number:");
    int num = scan.nextInt();
    
    for(int count = 1; count <= 7; count++)
    {
        if (num < rnd)
        {
          System.out.println("Your guess is too low.");
        }
        else if (num > rnd)
        {
          System.out.println("Your guess is too high.");
        }
        else if ((Math.abs(rnd - num) == 1) || (Math.abs(rnd - num) == 2))
        {
          System.out.println("But your guess is VERY close.");
        }
        else
          System.out.println("You got it right!");

        System.out.println("Enter Next number: ");
        num = scan.nextInt();
    }
  }
}
```

It should work Fine.Basically Your reasoning wass wrong because You are putting a while loop inside a for loop. What you want to do is you want only 7 iteration.In those 7 iterations you are checking the conditions based on user Input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rebuild you code to make it more clear.

- Split the title (with description of the task)
- Split main loop where you read user input and check it with expected number
- Split output of the final result, where you print the result.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    final int rnd = new Random().nextInt(101);
    final int maxAttempts = 7;

    System.out.println("The program is going to give a number that is between 0 and 100 (including them).");
    System.out.println("You can guess it within maximum " + maxAttempts + " attempts by pressing Run.");
    boolean success = false;

    for (int attempt = 1; attempt <= maxAttempts && !success; attempt++) {
        System.out.format("(%s of %s) Enter your number: ", attempt, maxAttempts);
        int num = scan.nextInt();

        if (num == rnd)
            success = true;
        else {
            System.out.print("Your guess is too " + (num > rnd ? "high" : "low") + '.');
            System.out.println(Math.abs(rnd - num) <= 2 ? " But it's VERY close." : "");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(success ? "You got it right!" : "Bad luck this time. Buy.");
}
```